# Which Hooks are called if an invoice gets created/updated - directly by an admin and for example if the user pays his bills?

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-modules

i want to sync the invoices automatically. Which hooks are called if an invoice gets created or updated?

I am using prestashop 8.

Thank you for your help!

Greetings

Marc

I already tried the actionValidateOrder and actionInvoiceAdd.

Comment: Did you try: https://devdocs.prestashop-project.org/8/modules/concepts/hooks/list-of-hooks/actionobjectclassnameaddafter/ and https://devdocs.prestashop-project.org/8/modules/concepts/hooks/list-of-hooks/actionobjectclassnameupdateafter/ ?